# What are proper translations of "What does your friend love to do?"

Tags: gramática

Memrise.com has a lesson containing the following translation:

> ¿Qué le encanta hacer a tu amigo?
>
> What does your friend love to do?

My brain is telling me that the above Spanish translates to:

> What does he love to do to your friend?

Adding more to my confusion is that web-based translation engines give me the following translation:

> What do you love to your friend?
>
> What do you love to do to your friend?
>
> What does he love doing to your friend?
>
> What do you love your friend?

Is Memrise.com incorrect, or am I just not understanding how this Spanish sentence is constructed?

Furthermore, if the sentence does indeed translate to "What does your friend love to do", then how does one say the following in Spanish:

> What does he love to do to your friend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website is correct.
The question talks about what *thing* your friend loves to do.

The question *What does he love to do to your friend?* is different and translates to *¿Qué le gusta (a él) hacerle a tu amigo?*  or ¿*Qué es lo que le gusta (a él) hacerle a tu amigo?*

The verb **gustar** repeats object pronouns. For instance,

> Me **gusta** bañar**me**.

If we write this as

> Me **gusta** bañar,

it's not clear who or what we are addressing. By adding the second **me** alludes that I (myself) like to take a shower.

Comment: After pondering you answer for a bit, it now makes perfect sense to me! You've really enlightened me with this one!

Comment: @RockAnthonyJohnson I have to say it was hard to explain, so I glad I did my best.